# using sklearn linear regression fit on timeseries + plotting

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have the following timeseries outputted by get_DP():

```
                DP
date              
1900-01-31  0.0357
1900-02-28  0.0362
1900-03-31  0.0371
1900-04-30  0.0379
...            ...
2015-09-30  0.0219

[1389 rows x 1 columns]
```

*note: There is a DP value for every month from 1900-2015, I simply excluded  them to avoid clutter*

I want to use a simple regression on this DataFrame to calculate the alpha & beta (intercept and coefficient resectively) of this financial variable. I have the following code that is intended to do so:

```
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
df = get_DP()
df=df.reset_index()
reg.fit(df['date'].values.reshape((1389,1)), df['DP'].values)
print("beta: {}".format(reg.coef_))
print("alpha: {}".format(reg.intercept_))
plt.scatter(df['date'].values.reshape((1389,1)), df['DP'].values,  color='black')
plt.plot(df['date'].values.reshape((1389,1)), df['DP'].values, color='blue', linewidth=3)
```

However, I believe the reshaping of my x-axis data (the dates) messes up the entire regression, because the plot looks like so:
[image: plot]

Am I making a mistake? I'm not entirely sure what the best tool is for regression w/ DataFrame's since pandas removed their OLS function with 0.20.

Comment: It seems to me that this is not a problem of regression, but more of dimension of the plot. If you reshape your x-axis, the dots may appear less vertical ;)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, I excluded a lot of data to remove clutter in this post, but there's a DP value for  the end of every month from 1900 to 2015. Shouldn't there be a dot across the ENTIRE x-axis?

Answer (score 2):

try this one

```py
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
df = get_DP()
df=df.reset_index()
reg.fit(df.date.values.reshape(-1, 1), df.DP.values.reshape(-1, 1))
print("beta: {}".format(reg.coef_))
print("alpha: {}".format(reg.intercept_))
plt.scatter(df.date.dt.date, df.DP.values,  color='black')
plt.plot(df.date.dt.date, df.DP.values, color='blue', linewidth=3)
```

See [reshape documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html)

Comment: So it is the reshaping that's the issue, but I'm not sure what it means or changes. What is the significance of those values for these dataframes?

Comment: but main problem was `date` plot do not work with `datetime64[ns]` today [howto](https://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html?highlight=how#plot-numpy-datetime64-values).

Or try pandas plotting it's very helpful. [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html)

Comment: Do you mean `reshape(-1, 1)`? 
It is just to shape as vector (column) not a row. 
'values' is 1D np.array but `sklearn` expects matrix.